# Upload/Download file to/from Google Drive using Google Cloud services in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, download, upload, google-drive-api

I have spent quite some time trying to find an example of how to use Google Drive with VB.net. All examples seem to be in other languages - usually C. I found a Youtube video on exactly what I wanted (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZUn3ofWbJk&t=471s), but even that was no use in the end, as part-way through (1:16) it demonstrated copying and pasting a "secret ID" Google API services - a page I could not find - I looked under "credentials" similar to the video and did not get a "secret ID" as they were demonstrating to copy and paste...

Can anyone lead me to a good VB.net example program for uploading/downloading to Google Drive? Many thanks!

Comment: Hello, please make sure you take the [tour] before posting and also read [ask] and try to follow [mcve]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ah, nothings been done, as I can't find any VB.net examples on how to work with Google drive? I've really told all I have done - which is simply scouring the Internet for VB examples